# while inserting records in mysql, argument values are passing as 0 in python

Tags: python, pandas

In console.log I am getting the correct argument value, but when I try to add the argument value in the insert statement it is passing as 0. As a whole, the code works fine without errors, but for `assg_id`, instead of the actual value, it is inserting 0.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
print ("parameters from nodejs", str(sys.argv[1]))
df = pd.read_csv("./userSetupData.csv")
df.head()

import mysql.connector as msql
from mysql.connector import Error
try:
    conn = msql.connect(host='localhost', database='pythonTest', user='root', password='0000', auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
    if conn.is_connected():
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select database();")
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        assgn_id = str(sys.argv[1])
        print('Checking the parameter value', assgn_id)
        for i,row in df.iterrows():
            #here %S means string values 
            sql = "INSERT INTO pythonTest.usr_stg VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,assgn_id)"
            cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
            print("Record inserted")
            # the connection is not auto committed by default, so we must commit to save our changes
            conn.commit()
except Error as e:
            print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: You can't use string `assgn_id` in SQL to put its value. SQL treats it as normal string or column's name, not python's variable. You have to add it to `tuple(row)` - probably `tuple( row + [assgn_id] )` and put `%s` instead `assgn_id` in query. OR you could use `f-string` - `f"INSERT .... {assgn_id})"`

Comment: `argv` keeps all values as strings (even numbers) - so you don't need `str()`

Comment: Thank you @furas, both the method worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sql` has normal string and it treats `assgn_id` as normal text in string, not Python's variable

You would have to use `f-string` and `"{assgn_id}"` to put value in this string

```
sql = f"INSERT INTO pythonTest.usr_stg VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, {assgn_id})"
```

Or you should put `assgn_id` in tuple with parameters (and use `%s` in query)

```
sql = "INSERT INTO pythonTest.usr_stg VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s)"

cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row.to_list() + [assgn_id]) )
```